# Meaning of `mesg n || true` in bash profile

Tags: linux, shell, profile

A `~/.profile` I encountered had this line at the bottom. I understand `mesg` toggles seeing other's messages, but what about the `|| true` part ? What does that achive in the context of a `.profile` file ?

Comment: is that the whole line? show us the block if you would please. `x || true` is a condition that will always return true, regardless of the value for x. the `||` is a boolean (logical) OR operator, and will return true if either of its operands are true. ORs are generally used in conditional statements like `if` or `while` or `until`.

Comment: Yes, as it appears. This was not in any block.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the manual, `mesg`'s return code depends on the status of the message appearance. It can either return 0, 1 without indicating an error. `|| true` is used to ensure the return code is `0` in order not to influence the environment in case `1` is returned by `mesg`.

Comment: I had a suspicion it was something like that. I spend most of my time with compiled languages so I was thinking it was somthing like "don't crash just because `mesg` did", but your analysis seems spot-on. +1